# Is there a way to make sure the section title always ends up in the header?

Tags: header-footer

The current headers in my document are coded as follows.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\rmdefault}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\textit{Monzur Rahman}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textit{Page \thepage}}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\textit{Monzur Rahman}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textit{Page \thepage}}


\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\gdef\leftmark{\thesection\quad#1}\gdef\rightmark{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\gdef\rightmark{\thesubsection\quad#1}}

\section{Lorem}
\subsection{Ipsum}
\lipsum[1-15]
\newpage

\section{Dolor}
\subsection{Sit}

\end{document}
```

This means that if the section starts on an even-numbered page, the header will show the subsection title instead of the title. Now the obvious solution is to just add in a blank page, but I would prefer to save paper. So is there another solution?

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Especially that example should contain an example of a section that does not go to the header.

Comment: You could create a new pagestyle and use \thispagestyle{...} to force the \sectionmark on either odd or even pages.